# Is Kol still Original Vampire after resurrected by Davina?

Tags: the-originals

Davina resurrect Kol in S03E14.
So is Kol still Original Vampire after resurrected by Davina?.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes. From [Kol Mikaelson Wikia](http://vampirediaries.wikia.com/wiki/Kol_Mikaelson)

> In *A Streetcar Named Desire*, Kol is successfully resurrected in his true form as an Original Vampire by Davina.